# How to order by just the Time Field in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to create a class schedule.  I need to get the time field to sort correctly to display the class schedule in the correct order.  Currently it is not, and I don't understand what I need to do to get it sorting correctly.

Here is the live link: http://studio34yoga.com/yoga-movement/class-schedule/  You can see on Monday that the classes are not in the correct order.  "start_time" is my time picker field that I am hoping to sort on.  What follows is an abridged version of my PHP code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Classes', 'posts_per_page' => 70, 'meta_key' => 'start_time', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order'=>'ASC' );       
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );


while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

if(get_field('day') == "2monday") :

{
    echo '<div class="class"><span class="class-time">';
    echo get_field('start_time');
    echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp;';
    echo get_field('end_time');
    echo '</span></div>';
}

endif;

endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: How are you storing the time? Are you using the date and time picker add on? http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/date-time-picker/ Or manually entering it? And in what format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the times are being stored as plain text strings like "10:00 am - 12:00 pm" which will be pretty impossible to sort correctly during your wp_query call.

Try the [date and timepicker add-on](http://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-field-date-time-picker/) and it should allow you to store in a sortable format. You can use it for only times and not dates. Then if you need a time range, you can have "start_time" and "end_time" and then sort by "start_time".

Comment: THanks for your help on this... I will look closer at it.  I thought I was using the date / time picker, as it gives me a time chooser interface -- It is not just a text field.

Comment: If you are using it, it should store in the database as a unix timestamp which is great for ordering... Let me know if you are using that, or if you are using a different add-on. Would curious to see why it is not working.

Comment: Thanks, Jake.  I have the date / time field installed and activated, which I am assuming is what would be giving me the field.  I have no other addons / plugins that I would be using.  Everything I read on this seems to talk about ordering by date, and it's not as helpful for me to understand how to order by time.

Comment: I tried to test, but the date/time field doesn't work right for me... It saves a nice timestamp into the db, but it doesn't show in the metafield after. So all I can say is make sure that you have "Save as timestamp?" set to "Yes".

Comment: I did make sure it was ordering right based on the time I stored. I am having a problem with using "get_field('start_time')", but when i just did a get_post_meta it worked for me, and it ordering correctly. If you are still having trouble, you should look in the database at the wp_postmeta table and find some entries with "start_date" as their "meta_key" and see what they look like.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help on this.  The other thing that is really wonky is that any time I go to edit the class, the time needs to be reentered.  I am thinking that the problem is more with the timefield than it is with my code.  I'm going to set up my own time field in ACF and see if that will work better for me.  I sincerely appreciate your help on this!  I will follow up in a day or two when I get it working and let you know my solution ;)

Comment: That is the same problem I had with the time field. I think that it is broken unfortunately... It storesto the database correctly, but it doesn't retrieve from the database correctly. I might start by contacting the plugin developer directly and see if they can fix it, because the alternatives with ACF aren't ideal... Good luck with whatever you land on!

Comment: Thanks, Jake -- This resolved itself with the latest update to ACF and ACF date / time picker.  You were so helpful for me to determine that it wasn't me but the plugin! :)

Comment: Great! I will have use for it myself in the near future, so glad to hear it.